# Is it possible to write Visual Studio Code extensions in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to write *Visual Studio Code* extensions in C# and not in TypeScript? I need this because I want to call some .NET DLLs.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917409/visual-studio-code-language-server-extension-that-written-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer involves a combination of native node modules, pre building and packaging them within your extension and restricting your extension to Windows users only. More information in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/658.

Comment: Isn't Blazor can be used to run pre-compiled C# inside a browser? As far as I understand VS Code is using electron which is some kind of a browser.

Comment: Clearly this answer is 4 years old. C# will enter the web-client world soon, through Blazor (which, by the way, is still a bit immature).