# visual studio code - language server extension that written in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-comparisons

I would like to write a visual studio code extension that parse and analyse large log files.

I thought to start with language server extension.

I would like the server to be written in python.

Below, there is an example to server that is written in TypeScript
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server
it uses the library "vscode-languageserver".

Is there any module in python equivalent to "vscode-languageserver"?

Do you know any example language server extension that is written in python?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281045/is-it-possible-to-write-visual-studio-code-extensions-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question but in case someone else is looking for this information:

I'm working on a [project](https://github.com/jondavid-black/AaC) that implements an LSP server in Python. To accomplish writing the language server in Python we are using a library called [pygls](https://github.com/openlawlibrary/pygls).

As with anything, it has its good and bad points but I can say that it has gotten the job done for the aforementioned project, so far.

Comment: Some nice resources referenced by pygls:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python-tools-extension-template
https://github.com/openlawlibrary/pygls/tree/main/examples/json-vscode-extension

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are at least two to take a look at:

- [python-langserver](https://github.com/sourcegraph/python-langserver) by Sourcegraph
- [python-language-server](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server) by Palantir

Unfortunately, I’m not familiar enough with Python to know which of these are the better choice.

Comment: thanks! do you know how can i find en example that show how to use those. I mean how to build a server to the extension with those modules?